# Bones deforming the mesh weirdly

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

In the image the hand rotates weirdly and becomes smaller, the torso also does that too but i don't really know what's happening on the jacket

I'm assuming that the gloves (and jacket sleeve) are probably just suffering from weight painting problems like the jacket

I need help i'm new to rigging models

.blend file
https://www.sendspace.com/file/d4unls
[image: https://www.sendspace.com/file/d4unls]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file so that we can try: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i had similar problems , which are unsolved

Comment: Well i fixed it by loading a backup before rigging and stuff and just rigged it again but i'll update the post with the failed version to see if anyone can fix it still